# How to find Version number of Onnx?

Tags: onnx, onnxruntime

How do I tell if I have Onnx 1.5 installed?   Why doesn't the onnxruntime.dll have it's "fileversion" set which would make things simple.  Is there an API call (in C/C++) to ask the version number?

Answer (score 1):

- Are you asking about onnx or onnxruntime?
- For onnxruntime, [this commit](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/commit/766c6b61633c3b66e523d0b0184ed57aca1768bc) in the master branch exposes an API to fetch the version. This API is not available in any current releases.
- Version compatibility between onnx and onnxruntime is documented here: https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/blob/master/docs/Versioning.md

Answer (score 0):

Which package are you using? If you are using python packages then the easiest way to get the version number is :

You can either use pip list to find the version for example : 
pip list | findstr onnx (on Windows and grep on Linux)

Alternatively you can also query the __version__ attribute of the module. For example
import onnx (or onnxruntime)
onnx.__version__ (or onnxruntime.__version__)

If you are using nuget packages then the package name should have the version. You can also use nuget package explorer to get more details for the package.